# Skip printing dialog on Debian

Tags: linux, printing, printer, gnome

If you are running a ticket application on desktops, how would you limit the users to make any change to the printing job configuration?

Ticket application is an [electron app](https://electronjs.org/). Currently it launches the printing dialog as any other application would. Running Debian 8 with Gnome 3. No problem if another DE or DM is required. It's ok if the printing options are locked system-wide.

Comment: Most of the printing options that can actually cause a problem are already locked system-wide. Are you concerned with something specific?

Comment: Mainly, I don't want the user to be able to make changes to the number of copies of the tickets (should always be 1), page dimensions and orientation.